# saveStringToLocalFile in WindowsPhone 8.1 in Universal 8.1 App C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, local-files

I have this Function:

```
   public async static Task<JsonObject> GetObject(string api)
        {
            try
            {

                JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
                if (!IsInternetConnected())
                {
                    string x = await DataBase.readStringFromLocalFile(api + ".txt");
                    jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(x);
                }
                else
                {
                    string x = "";
                    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("DataLibrary/apis.xml");
                    var items = doc.Descendants("string");
                    foreach (XElement item in items)
                    {
                        if (item.Attribute("name").Value == api)
                        {
                            HttpClient webclient = new HttpClient();

                            HttpResponseMessage resp = webclient.PostAsync(new Uri(item.Value.ToString()), null).Result; //here
                            x = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                            try
                            {
                                await DataBase.saveStringToLocalFile(api + ".txt", x);
                                Debug.WriteLine("after writing");

                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                throw ex;
                            }

                            Debug.WriteLine("after after writing");
                            jsonObject = JsonObject.Parse(x);
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
                return jsonObject;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MainPage.ShowCustomMessage(request_error_allert);
                return new JsonObject();

            }
        }
```

And this is the saveStringToFile Function that I took from this article: https://pumpkinszwan.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/read-and-write-text-files-windows-8-1-phone-8-1-universal-apps/

```
 public static async Task saveStringToLocalFile(string filename, string content)
        {
            // saves the string 'content' to a file 'filename' in the app's local storage folder
            byte[] fileBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content.ToCharArray());
            Debug.WriteLine("1");

            // create a file with the given filename in the local folder; replace any existing file with the same name
            StorageFile newFile = await Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            Debug.WriteLine("2");

            // write the char array created from the content string into the file
            using (var stream = await newFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
            {
                await stream.WriteAsync(fileBytes, 0, fileBytes.Length);
                Debug.WriteLine("3");
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("4");
        }
```

I am calling GetObject 2 times with 2 different APIs. 
When the code reaches the saveStringToFile Function, it crashes:

- sometimes it crashes inside the saveStringTofile after
  Debug.WriteLine("1");
- sometimes after Debug.WriteLine("2");
- sometimes after Debug.WriteLine("3");
- sometimes after Debug.WriteLine("after writing");
- sometimes it works the first time with the first API and crashes
  with the second.

Its behaviour is really weird, I am trying to catch it with every breakpoint but it crashes randomly every single time. Anything I am missing?

Comment: Are you trying to create the same file two times at the same time?

Comment: I don't think so because the two files have different filenames. The thing is: this same function was working on Windows Phone 8.1 but is not working in Universal.WindowsPhone 8.1 now...

Comment: It's weird if you call it with different name. Is it possible that the file is opened/not properly closed somewhere else? Have you tried to use *GenerateUniqueName* instead of *ReplaceExisting* - does it crash then? Have you tried to put this into *try-catch* block and see what exception is being thrown? Does *UnhandledException* get called?

Comment: When I use _GenerateUniqueName_ and walk in it step by step, break point by break point it doesn't crash. Is there a way to delete a file in the _LocalFolder_ explicitly before creating a new one?

Comment: If you try to delete a file which is being used somewhere, then you will get exception. Generaly using ReplaceExisting should be fine, probably problem is somewhere else. Have you tried to check what kind of exception you get?

Comment: UnhandledException get called, the problem is I can't catch it...

Comment: I am using a readStringFromLocalFile after it. I uses:  `Stream stream = await local.OpenStreamForReadAsync(filename);` and  `using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                text = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }` There's no method to close the Read Stream but I guess it is not opened, so the file is not being used. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Put your Stream into using: `using(Stream stream = await local.OpenStreamForReadAsync(filename)) { .. code .. }` - I guess this may be the problem, without using, stream is not disposed and may result in exception when trying to access a file for the second time.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37253987/access-resourcedictionary-in-windows-phone-project-from-shared-project-in-app-xa ?

Comment: As for now - no. So has putting `using` finally solved the problem of this question?

Comment: The problem I had was from some undefinded fields in a ResourceDictionary containing Styles that were used in my Page. It made the app crashes on these SaveStringToFile and Frame.Navigate methods. Thanks a lot for your help @Romasz!