# Access ResourceDictionary in Windows Phone project from Shared project in App.xaml of Universal 8.1 App

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app, resourcedictionary

I am creating a Windows Universal 8.1 app. In the Windows Phone 8.1 project inside I have a certain Xaml file as ResourceDictionary. 
In the Shared Folder I have the common App.xaml of the 2 projects (Windows and Windows Phone).

Path of ResourceDictionary is: `"MyApp.WindowsPhone/Assets/Styles/JumpList.xaml"`

In App.xaml I add:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
   <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="MyApp.WindowsPhone/Assets/Styles/JumpList.xaml"/>
   </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

But I am getting:

```
An error occured while finding the resource dictionary "MyApp.WindowsPhone/Assets/Styles/JumpList.xaml"
```

Any idea what's wrong in my Path?

Answer (score 0):

Since `MyApp.WindowsPhone` is the root folder you don't need to specify  it you can state it as 
`<ResourceDictionary Source="/Assets/Styles/JumpList.xaml"/>`
Usually we declare styles inside a new folder named Styles as Assets folder is meant for adding image files according to norms.

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="/Styles/JumpList.xaml"/>
```

Comment: App.xaml exists in the Shared Folder, I also have a MyApp.Windows folder and a MyApp.WndowsPhone folder. So MyApp.WndowsPhone is not my root folder...

Comment: Yes But universal app when it gets deployed to mobile device it takes the mobile folder and adds the shared folder to it so your mobile folder becomes the root. Did your styles work when you changed the path?

Comment: Yes it worked when I put my ResourceDictionary in the Shared folder and named the path as you said! But it seems I have a problem in my ResourceDictionary. I am styling a JumpList in it and I am getting this error: `Error 13 Unknown type 'JumpListItemBackgroundConverter' in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'` Any idea about this error?

Comment: `JumpListItemBackgroundConverter` being a custom name, there might be two options 1) Since `Converter` name is used there must be a 'Converter' class defined somewhere in your phone project you will need to shift it to shared folder also if you are shifting it. 2) If by `Jumplist` you mean `ListView` enclosed in `semantic zoom` then you will have to check if you are not defining any phone themed resource in it.